# Google-speech-api transcribing spoken numbers incorrectly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I started using google speech api to transcribe audio.

The audio being transcribed contains many numbers spoken one after the other.

E.g. 273 298

But the transcription comes back 270-3298

My guess is that it is interpreting it as some sort of phone number.

What i want is unparsed output e.g. "two seventy three two ninety eight' which i can deal with and parse on my own.

Is there a setting or support for this kind of thing?

thanks

Comment: Are you requesting more than one alternative? If so, do any of the others get the transcription correct?

Comment: i get 10 alternatives, and all of them have the number formated as a phone number

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Application asks users to enter a 9 digit card number, Google thinks the user is trying to say a phone number so it pads the results with an extra digit at the end or even the middle of a number.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55525503/api-or-sdk-to-make-speech-recognition-only-for-numbers-between-1-and-10000/

Comment: Try IBM's SR service, which provides a "smart_format" option to tweak whether return the original transcripts or "formatted" one

Answer (score 5):

So I had this exact same problem and I think we found a solution. If you're using English as input, switch to en-PH just when working with numbers. Google will then not format the result as a U.S. phone number or try to stick an extra digit in there.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing a speech context with some phrase hints.  How to use it is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics#phrase-hints

Give it the spelled out numbers that you want recognized.

```
"speech_context": {
  "phrases":["zero", "one", "two", ... "nine", "ten", "eleven", ... "twenty", "thirty,..., "ninety"]
 }
```

This isn't guaranteed to work, but it may help.

Comment: We tried this as well and unfortunately we are still seeing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I tried blambert's solution above and it doesn't work, unfortunately.  I posted another question recently seeing if anyone has found a way to defeat this behavior, as it is preventing me from implementing a transcription service that I had planned.

Comment: For the record, Amazon's speech recognition software doesn't seem to format numbers into phone numbers.  I may have to take a look at that again if I can't work around this with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Google Speech [customClass](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/class-tokens)?

You have some class tokens that you could use, telling the API that you are not expecting a phone number but a different type of numbers.

For instance, if you choose to use OOV_CLASS_AM_RADIO_FREQUENCY, you'll indicate the API to interpret numbers like this:

- "twelve twenty"  --> 1220
- "seven hundred and thirty"   --> 730

Probably (haven't read this) the API is using this class FULLPHONENUM by defaut for numbers:

- "one eight hundred five five five four oh oh one"    --> +1-800-555-4001
- "seven one eight five five five six one oh one"  --> 718-555-6101