# Google Speech API - numbers represented as strings?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I am using Google Speech API and whenever in the utterance there is a number spoken the API returns it as a string of digits and not letters. Say the utterance is 'He is seventeen years old.' - The API would return 'He is 17 years old.' Now that is useful most of the cases, but in my case I need the returned string to be of letters not digits - 'He is seventeen years old.'
Is there any option to return the recognized utterance with letters?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's a way with [Phrase hints](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#phrase-hints). The API will offer the option to transcribe numbers literally in the future, but there is no timeline for this feature yet.

this question is quite a duplicate:

[Google-speech-api transcribing spoken numbers incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893742/google-speech-api-transcribing-spoken-numbers-incorrectly/51757522)

[Is there a way to force Google Speech api to return only words as response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784797/is-there-a-way-to-force-google-speech-api-to-return-only-words-as-response)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will be waiting for this option. For now the Phrase hint workaround doesn't seem suitable for my project as I need to be working with a lot of languages and any kind of number so the work needed seems tremendous as I am not fluent in most of the languages.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/words-to-numbers)  .
Should cover your case of usage.

Comment: I need it to be working not only for English but for more languages. I did search for libraries but didn't find anything suitable.